# ODK Central redirected too many times at AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, odk

Im trying to self host the ODK Central using AWS EC2 instance and route it with load balancer so i can attach ACM SSL to its https connection. I can open ODK Central dashboard if I open the public IP address of my instance directly, but opening it through load balancer's DNS or my domain name results in ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error. what would possibly the cause for this?

I have tried installing simple apache webserver to test the load balancer and my domain connection, it seems working well. I also checked that the docker container listening to correct port in my instance. I am expecting my domain will open ODK Central dashboard